# Filling the available width? (image example)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three columns. Middle column is fixed content 600 pixels wide. How to make left and right columns to fill rest of the available space? I realized it is much more difficult than it seems. Is it possible with pure CSS?

[image]

Something similar to following jsfiddle example, but content width should be fixed.

jsfiddle.net/4EN4P/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dinjas/sP84P/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using multiple columns, just use the content column with `margin: 0 auto` and not floated and set the background color on the container.  You can remove all elements and styles for the left/right columns.  This of course assumes that those columns have no content.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/4EN4P/1/